# Android textview options in custom dialog

Tags: android, textview, customdialog

I created custom dialog and i have textview in it. Text is pretty close to edge of my dialog box, so i wonder if I can set some space between my text and left and right edge of dialog box and how ??

Answer (score 1):

In your custom dialog's xml layout add the following to the root:

```
android:padding="10dp"
```

Or whichever value you see fit.

Comment: Thanks, this work lika a charm. If I may aks also is it posible to justify text ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your `TextView` with some `marginLeft` and `marginRight` attributes.
These will put some space between your `TextView` and the left, right edges of the screen.

Also consider using `paddingLeft`, `paddingRight` attributes to ensure that there is some space between the border of your `TextView` and the actual text itself.

Look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) for more information about how you can set these parameters in a `TextView`.